# Array.delete(object) removes from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I was trying to just get an array of posts that do not include @post. To my surprise the code below resulted in @post being deleted from the database!

```
@post = Post.find(2)
@posts = Post.where(:text => "title")
@posts.delete(@post)
```

Why does an Array function delete @post from the database? Does Rails extend or overwrite this function? I thought only the .destroy function can delete objects from the database? I guess I am confused on what exactly the .where function returns and the consequences of using @ and not using @ for variables.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is stored in `@posts` after you do `Post.where(:text => 'title')` is not an array. It's a type of `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

When you call delete with `@post` as a parameter, you're telling Rails to delete that object from the database.

Comment: Here is the documentation of the method that is being called : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want an array returned, you could simply do something like this: `Post.where(:text => 'title').to_a`