# Rails 4 getting more detailed search results

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I grab a list of results from the database. then I ran an if statement to delete some of the results, however I don't want to delete the objects from the database, just from the list of results I pulled.

so whats the alternative method to .delete ([Array.delete(object) removes from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667924/array-deleteobject-removes-from-database))

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        results = where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
        results.each do |event|
            if (((event.edate + event.minduration.minute) - Time.now)/60).round.to_i > 0.to_i #if the event is over? remove it from the list.
                results.delete(event)
            end
        end
        results
    else
        Event.all
    end
end
```

Or perhaps it would be best to just limit the search results to begin with, but I don't know how to combine these two conditions into one line:

```
results = where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
((event.edate - Time.now)/60).round.to_i > 0.to_i
```

Can someone help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run it like this:-

```
results = where('title LIKE ? AND (event.edate - Time.now)/60).round.to_i > ?', "%#{search}%", 0.to_i)
```

Comment: That gave an error about a bad number of arguments, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224600/can-you-do-greater-than-comparison-on-a-date-in-a-rails-3-search which looked promising but the > Time.now doesn't actually work. Then I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514539/math-with-datetime-in-sql-query-in-rails That gave an error about TIME_TO_SEC not being valid so maybe thats a version issue or something.

Comment: I forgot to put ? For second condition, could you please try now.

Comment: And also make sure that time.now format is same as that of event.edate

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in EventsController#index
SQLite3::SQLException: near ".": syntax error: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (title LIKE '%asdf%' AND (event.edate - Time.now)/60).round.to_i > 0)

Extracted source (around line #17):

17    if !results.blank?